# How to get info on disk drives with powershell

Tags: shell-script, hard-disk, disk, utilities, powershell

Is it not possible to install `Get-Disk` on [Linux](https://superuser.com/a/1147305/55747)?

```
PS /home/thufir/powershell> 
PS /home/thufir/powershell> Get-Module -ListAvailable


    Directory: /home/thufir/.local/share/powershell/Modules

ModuleType Version    Name                                PSEdition ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                --------- ----------------
Script     0.0.7      PSTwitterAPI                        Desk      {Get-TwitterGeo_Id_PlaceId, Send-TwitterOauth_AccessToken, Send…
Script     2.1.3      SSHSessions                         Desk      {New-SshSession, Invoke-SshCommand, Enter-SshSession, Remove-Ss…

    Directory: /snap/powershell/77/opt/powershell/Modules

ModuleType Version    Name                                PSEdition ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                --------- ------------Manifest   1.2.3.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive        Desk      {Compress-Archive, Expand-Archive}
Manifest   6.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Host           Core      {Start-Transcript, Stop-Transcript}
Manifest   6.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     Core      {Add-Content, Clear-Content, Clear-ItemProperty, Join-Path…}
Manifest   6.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Security       Core      {Get-Credential, Get-ExecutionPolicy, Set-ExecutionPolicy, Conv…
Manifest   6.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        Core      {Export-Alias, Get-Alias, Import-Alias, New-Alias…}
Script     1.3.2      PackageManagement                   Desk      {Find-Package, Get-Package, Get-PackageProvider, Get-PackageSou…
Script     2.1.3      PowerShellGet                       Desk      {Find-Command, Find-DSCResource, Find-Module, Find-RoleCapabili…
Script     0.0        PSDesiredStateConfiguration         Desk      {Set-NodeResourceSource, Set-NodeResources, Node, Update-Depend…
Script     2.0.0      PSReadLine                          Desk      {Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler, Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler, Remove-PSR…
Binary     1.1.2      ThreadJob                           Desk      Start-ThreadJob

PS /home/thufir/powershell> 
PS /home/thufir/powershell> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Patch  PreReleaseLabel BuildLabel
-----  -----  -----  --------------- ----------
6      2      3                      

PS /home/thufir/powershell>
```

It [seems](https://superuser.com/a/1147305/55747) to work on Linux once it's installed.

Comment: you referenced a windows question

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you have powershell core installed to your linux box.

In order for you to get the cmdlet `Get-Disk` to work you would need to import the storage powershell module.

`Import-Module -Name Storage`

Once you have imported it you will be able to see the module with `Get-Module -ListAvailable`

In order to see the available cmdlets with the storage module you can type. `Get-Command -Module Storage`  you will see that you have get disk as well as many more storage modules.

In order to ensure you have updated help type `Update-Help -Verbose` and all of your modules and cmdlets will get their associated help files updated.